# Cannot add restriction to oneToMany mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 2 entities linked together using oneToMany mapping. In the Dao layer when i apply restrictions on the linked entity it fetches all the results. It seems that the restrictions are not working on the linked entity. I want to apply restrictions on both entities.

**DAO**

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria()
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("status" , "APPROVED"))
                .addOrder(Order.desc("approvedAt"))
                .createAlias("purchaseDemandDetails" , "pds")
                .add(Restrictions.ge("pds.approvedQuantity" , 1));
        return criteria.list();
```

**PurchaseDemand.java**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User createdBy;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by" , referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "approved_by" , referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User approvedBy;

    @Column(name = "approved_at")
    private Date approvedAt;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchaseDemand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PurchaseDemandDetail> purchaseDemandDetails = new HashSet<PurchaseDemandDetail>();
    public void setPurchaseDemandDetails(Set<PurchaseDemandDetail> purchaseDemandDetails)
    {
        this.purchaseDemandDetails.addAll(purchaseDemandDetails);
    }
    public Set<PurchaseDemandDetail> getPurchaseDemandDetails()
    {
        return this.purchaseDemandDetails;
    }
```

**PurchaseDemandDetail.java**

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_demand_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private PurchaseDemand purchaseDemand;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "requested_quantity", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Quantity is required")
    private int requestedQuantity;

    @Column(name = "approved_quantity", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Quantity is required")
    private int approvedQuantity;
}
```

Comment: whats behind createEntityCriteria()?

Comment: Its a method in abstract class that i extended. `protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }`